# AcceptTcpClientAsync returns, but no data is available

Tags: .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

Scenario: I'm kicking off an authentication flow using a browser. After the user authenticates, the browser redirects to http://localhost:1234, for which I listen. I then extract an auth code from the URI.

The problem is that sometimes the `TCPListner.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` returns a TcpClient, indicating that a connection was formed, but no data exists? Should I call `TCPListner.AcceptTcpClientAsync` repeatedly?

```cs
listener.Start();

// Gets triggered when an incoming connection occurs
TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();

// But sometimes data just isn't available?
Console.WriteLine(" -> DataAvailable? " + networkStream.DataAvailable);


// Standard pattern of reading data from a stream
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

do
{
    // this just waits indefinitely as no timeout is set
    int numberOfBytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, ct)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
    stringBuilder.Append(s);

}
while (networkStream.DataAvailable);
```

This code seems to work fine in most browsers except Edge, where about 50% of the time `AcceptTcpClientAsync` returns a TcpClient, but that client has no data.

I've inspected the network using TcpView and it looks like there are several connections being formed, one of them having 0 bytes sent.

Comment: listener should be initiated only once .but you are trying to initiating in every connection.how it can be possible ?

Comment: DataAvailable is not a good property to loop on. You could end up with half a message if the timing was just right

Comment: @Mr.AF - I dispose of the listener elsewhere.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain official source says it's correct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?view=netframework-4.8